# AutoMapper - deserialize dynamic value within collection not working

Tags: c#, json, automapper

I'm trying to use automapper in order to fulfill the DTO mapping here, and I have the following situation:

When storing `Value` into the database, I'm stringifying the JSON attribute using the following:

```
var serializedValue = JsonSerializer.Serialize(cardAttribute.Value);
```

I need to have this card attribute value parsed back to an object or a dynamic property (as stated below), in order to return a proper JSON value and not a stringified value as an output. The problem is my mapping is not working properly.

First, those are the entities and the DTOs I have:

```
// Annotations hidden for simplicity purposes.

// entities:
public class CardEntity : BaseEntity
{
    public string? Id { get; set; }
    public string? GameId { get; set; }
    public List<CardAttributeEntity> Attributes { get; set; } = new();
}
public class CardAttributeEntity : BaseEntity
{
    public string? CardId { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; } = "";
    public string Value { get; set; } = "";
    public string Language { get; set; } = "";
    public bool Searchable { get; set; } = true;   
}

// DTOs:
public record CardOutput(
  string Id,
  string GameId,
  List<CardAttributeOutput> Attributes,
  DateTime CreatedAt,
  DateTime? UpdatedAt);

public record CardAttributeOutput(
    string CardId,
    string Key,
    dynamic Value,
    string Language,
    DateTime CreatedAt,
    DateTime? UpdatedAt,
    bool Searchable = true);
```

My mapping class is looking like the following:

```
public class CardProfile : Profile
{
    public CardProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<CardInput, CardEntity>().ReverseMap();
        CreateMap<CardEntity, CardOutput>().ReverseMap();
        CreateMap<CardAttributeInput, CardAttributeEntity>().ReverseMap();
        CreateMap<CardAttributeFromAsset, CardAttributeEntity>().ReverseMap()
            .ForMember(
                d => d.Value,
                opt => opt.MapFrom(s => JsonSerializer.Deserialize<dynamic>(s.Value, JsonSerializerOptions.Default)));

    }
}
```

---

UPDATED 1:
A data sample might help understanding the data model:

```
        "id": "651e6eecd9234565138ab977",
        "gameId": "651e6eecd9234565138ab976",
        "attributes": [
            {
                "cardId": "651e6eecd9234565138ab977",
                "key": "flavor-text",
                "value":"\"\'(Order of Merlin, First Class, Grand Sorc., Chf. Warlock, Supreme Mugwump, International Confed. of Wizards)\' \— Hogwarts letterhead\"",
                "language": "en",
                "createdAt": "2023-10-05T08:08:12.94Z",
                "updatedAt": null,
                "searchable": false
            },
            {
                "cardId": "651e6eecd9234565138ab977",
                "key": "images",
                "value": "[{\"language\":\"en\",\"url\":\"https://accioimgcdn.azureedge.net/cards/en/adventures_at_hogwarts/Albus_Dumbledore.jpg\"}]",
                "language": "en",
                "createdAt": "2023-10-05T08:08:12.94Z",
                "updatedAt": null,
                "searchable": true
            },
            {
                "cardId": "651e6eecd9234565138ab977",
                "key": "slug-sub-types",
                "value": "[\"wizard\",\"unique\"]",
                "language": "fr",
                "createdAt": "2023-10-05T08:08:12.941Z",
                "updatedAt": null,
                "searchable": true
            },
        ],
        "createdAt": "2023-10-05T08:08:12.94Z",
        "updatedAt": null
```

---

UPDATED 2:
With `JsonNode`, I can save most of the values as they should be, thanks to @Fildor's reply! However, there is a problem with arrays. Is there a property I can pass to JsonNode to cast them without explicitly casting or converting?

```
                "value": "[\n  {\n    \"language\": \"en\",\n    \"url\": \"https://accioimgcdn.azureedge.net/cards/en/adventures_at_hogwarts/Albus_Dumbledore.jpg\"\n  }\n]",
```

As you can see, the `value` attribute is stringified on my MongoDB collection, and that's the one I want to parse to an object to be returned back to the requester.

Can someone give me some light in here?
Thank y'all!

Comment: So which entities/models used for the source and destination? Can you provide the sample data?

Comment: @YongShun I've added some data sample to the question for helping out in this understanding!

Comment: Would it be an option (possible) to _not_ stringify, but have a `JsonNode` typed `Value` property instead?

Comment: @Fildor that might be an option. Let me try with a `JsonNode` property and I'll come back with results!

Comment: @Fildor almost there! The idea of `JsonNode` worked for most of the cases. However, please check the example in the updated question: arrays are not converted out of the box. Is there a way to configure JsonNode for converting them without strongly typing or casting?